# Launching Wiki js on node js via systemd services

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, wiki

If I start the server via putty

```
node server
```

The server starts perfectly

If I try to start the server via serverd, an error occurs

```
* wiki.service - Wiki.js

   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wiki.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2022-10-03 13:35:00 MSK; 5s ago
  Process: 6447 ExecStart=/usr/bin/node server (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6447 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 03 13:35:00  node[6447]:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
Oct 03 13:35:00  node[6447]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/wiki/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/index.js:3:44)
Oct 03 13:35:00  node[6447]:     at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
Oct 03 13:35:00  node[6447]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
Oct 03 13:35:00  node[6447]:     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
Oct 03 13:35:00  node[6447]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
Oct 03 13:35:00  node[6447]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
Oct 03 13:35:00  node[6447]:     at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
Oct 03 13:35:00  node[6447]: (node:6447) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise whic
Oct 03 13:35:00  node[6447]: (node:6447) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
```

if I allow the wiki user to enter the terminal and try to launch it from there

```
node server
```

then the error is as follows

```
Loading configuration from /var/www/wiki/config.yml... OK
2022-10-03T10:19:40.835Z [MASTER] info: =======================================
2022-10-03T10:19:40.837Z [MASTER] info: = Wiki.js 2.5.289 =====================
2022-10-03T10:19:40.837Z [MASTER] info: =======================================
2022-10-03T10:19:40.837Z [MASTER] info: Initializing...
(node:6326) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: /var/www/wiki/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/make-dir           .js:85
      } catch {
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/wiki/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/index.js:3:44)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
(node:6326) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated eith           er by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was            not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6326) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future,            promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code           .
```

ubuntu 18.04
node v16.17.1 ltc

Answer (score 0):

the problem I had was in the environment. wiki node was launched by default with version 8.7.1. It was required to log in under the user and install the desired version from under him. The problem has been solved